# Terraform Enable or Disable Parameter inside resource block and also resource block?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am defining network interface inside the VMSS AZURE Terraform
Well what i want is disable or enable the load balancer backend address pool id if $app != "api"
In other words if app is api then only add that parameter and attach pool id.

Also, How to enable or disable entire resource lets say i want to diable or enable the network interface block in whole.

Thanks in advance for helping.

```
load_balancer_backend_address_pool_ids       = [var.backend_address_pool_id] #enable only when var.app is api.
```

```
network_interface {
    name    = "${var.app}-vmss-nic"
    primary = true
    ip_configuration {
      name                                         = "internal"
      primary                                      = true
      subnet_id                                    = var.pvt_subnet_1_id
      load_balancer_backend_address_pool_ids       = [var.backend_address_pool_id]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need to test this but you could possible do something like

```
load_balancer_backend_address_pool_ids = var.app == "api" ? [var.backend_address_pool_id] : null
```

or incase the provider doesnt support null and just expects an empty list

```
load_balancer_backend_address_pool_ids = var.app == "api" ? [var.backend_address_pool_id] : []
```

Comment: thank you very much chris, the first one with null worked. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by using the ternary operator [1] and a combination of the `dynamic` block [2] with `for_each` meta-argument [3] for the network interface. To achieve this you would do the following:

```
dynamic "network_interface" {
   for_each = var.app == "api" ? [1] : [0]
   content {
    name    = "${var.app}-vmss-nic"
    primary = true
    ip_configuration {
      name                                         = "internal"
      primary                                      = true
      subnet_id                                    = var.pvt_subnet_1_id
      load_balancer_backend_address_pool_ids       = [var.backend_address_pool_id] 
    }
  }
}
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/conditionals

[2] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

[3] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each

Comment: Awesome, the example you gave helps to control entire block.

Answer (score 0):

When I have this kind of situation, I Always use this structure:

```
 dynamic "azure_devops_repo" {
  for_each = var.azure_devops_repo == null ? {} : var.azure_devops_repo
  iterator = devops
 content {
  account_name    = devops.value.account_name
  branch_name     = devops.value.branch_name
  project_name    = devops.value.project_name
  repository_name = devops.value.repository_name
  root_folder     = devops.value.root_folder
  tenant_id       = lookup(devops.value, "tenant_id", null)
 }
}
```

As you see this is like an optional block!

Comment: Thank you rafael  i will check this out too.